# Advanced routing to check multiple controllers in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to find a way to route URL's to their appropriate controller when the URL's are all off the root domain.

For example:

- `site.com/@username` - should go to Users controller
- `site.com/uk/london` - should go to Countries controller
- `site.com/fr/paris` - should go to Countries controller
- `site.com/bobs-farm` - should go to Farms controller

...and so on.

It's easy enough with says `site.com/users/username` but that's no good in this case.

What I need to do is pass the params to one controller, check if it's a match and if so, deal with - else pass it to the next controller and see if it fits there, and so on.

I could force everything into one giant catch-all controller but there's likely to be too much going on and it'll be way too unwieldy. Is there a way of doing this I can't figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a bit of a hacky workaround for the time being.

In `routes.php` I get the segments and if it's 1 segment, check it against the farms table and if it matches, it adds the route. Otherwise it continues to default routes. Similarly for 2 segments, I check against the countries data.

One thing I found was that a slug of the same name as a controller would override it. So, to be even more hacky, I pull a list of controllers and make sure a slug isn't in that before I generate the route.

It's probably quite monstrous but it works great so far. If there's a better way, I'm all ears though!

Answer (score 0):

To countries don't use "uk" and "fr" at least in this position. Usually these used to translations page.

for @username:

```
$route['^@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$'] = "Users/index/$1"; // $1 param to controller contain the username.
```

for farm

```
$route['^bobs-farm$'] = "Users/Farm";
```

for country

```
$route['^(fr|uk)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$']  = "Country/index/$1/$2"; // $1 param to controller contain the iso3 and $2 the country
```

**UPDATE FOR YOUR COMMENT**

To Farm:

Option 1:

```
$route['^farm/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$'] = "Farm/detail/$1";
```

Option 2

```
$route['^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-farm$'] = "Farm/detail/$1";
```

Comment: Yeah for username, that's easier as it has the @, but the others can be 200+ countries or 10,000+ farm entries with differing names. To manually enter them into the route would be somewhat impractical.

Comment: Yes, i will use the next slug to farm: /farm/unique-name-of-farm. If you do it, you maybe use url_title to generate unique slug

Comment: Or just use farm/farm-Id/farm-seo-title

Comment: Sure, I can do that easily enough but the problem here is they have to be written like above, I cannot put `farm/xxx` or ID's in there in this case.

Comment: @Wazzbast if you need that "site.com/bobs-farm" and "bobs-farm" is you identified to farm. Then put  the router farm line in the end with $route['^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$'] = "Farm/detail/$1"; If no matches then take the farm route, but I not recommended. I add a previous param.